# Angular Cannot load variable in app.module.ts from configuration.js

Tags: angular

In my app.module.ts am loading configuration variable from config/production.json which is in assets folders so that can be change after built has been deployed to iis server

The code on local is working fine it is fetching variables from configuration.json but one time the built has been deployed it is not getting the varibale from config file here is my angular code

My production.json file

```
{
     "production": true,
     "LogInapiUrl": "https://keenucfrs_public.keenu.pk/Develop/API/Vouchers/LogIn",
     "RecaptchaKey":"6LcNeewZAAAAAA3prujTXoskl05x0qLYwFGzUDas",
     "VoucherByChannelIdAPI":"https://keenucfrs_public.keenu.pk/Develop/API/Vouchers/GetVouchersByChannelId/",
     "ChannelAPI": "https://keenucfrs_public.keenu.pk/Develop/API/Vouchers/GetChannels",
     "PortalPath":"/Develop/Portal/ClientApp/"
}
```

Configservice for getting all the configuration variables

```
import { Injectable, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigServiceService {

    private _config: Object
    private _env: string;

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }
    load() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this._env = 'production';
            this._http.get('./assets/config/' + this._env + '.json')
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe((data) => {
                    this._config = data;
                    resolve(true);
                },
                (error: any) => {
                    console.error(error);
                    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
                });
        });
    }
    // Is app in the development mode?
    isDevmode() {
        return this._env === 'development';
    }
    // Gets API route based on the provided key
    getApi(key: string): string {
        return this._config["API_ENDPOINTS"][key];
    }
    // Gets a value of specified property in the configuration file
    get(key: any) {
        return this._config[key];
    }
}

export function ConfigFactory(config: ConfigServiceService) {
    return () => config.load();
}

export function init() {
    return {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: ConfigFactory,
        deps: [ConfigServiceService],
        multi: true
    }
}

const ConfigModule = {
    init: init
}

export { ConfigModule };
```

In my different commponent it is working fine

```
private  ChannelsAPI=this._configService.get("ChannelAPI");

 constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,private _configService:ConfigServiceService ) {}
```

But on app.module.ts file

Providers is declared before class so cannot use it in angular 10

Comment: Please provide the result when you tried to fetch value. Did you get error?

Comment: { provide: RECAPTCHA_V3_SITE_KEY, useValue:this.RecaptchaKey},


this.recaptchaKey is not defined 

But the same process is working on child component but not on app.module.ts

Comment: this.RecaptchaKey

 Object is possibly undefined

Comment: Why don't you set these values in `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` ?

Comment: Sorry I missed your requirement `so that can be change after built has been deployed to iis server`.

Comment: i want to use it by configuration so that it can be changed after the build has beed deployed

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had some help from a colleague and he suggested the following for the Recaptcha Key which is working.

The following tool tip popped up when he was looking at APP_INITIALIZER:

**An injection token that allows you to provide one or more initialization functions. These function are injected at application startup and executed during app initialization. If any of these functions returns a Promise, initialization does not complete until the Promise is resolved.*

*You can, for example, create a factory function that loads language data or an external configuration, and provide that function to the APP_INITIALIZER token. That way, the function is executed during the application bootstrap process, and the needed data is available on startup.**

The APP_INITIALIZER can be passed as a dependency and the function you are trying to run will be executed before the initialization.

I tried to use the code from above to show how the providers would look for initializing the service and then extracting the Recaptcha Key.

```
      providers: [
        ConfigServiceService,
        {
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          deps: [ConfigServiceService],
          useFactory: (configService: ConfigServiceService) => {
            return () => {
              //Make sure to return a promise!
              return configService.load();
            };
          },
          multi: true,
        },
        {
          provide: RECAPTCHA_V3_SITE_KEY,
          deps: [ConfigServiceService, APP_INITIALIZER],
          useFactory: (configService: ConfigServiceService) =>
            configService?.get("RecaptchaKey"),
        },
      ]
```